# How to filter out data out of a dataset?

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R. 
I'm looking to filter out some data so I'm left with only the data I want to work with.
The data called "Ireland" consists of columns titled - Year, OpennesstoTrade, Population, Inflation and TFP Growth.
The years go from 1984 - 2015.
I want to filter out the years 1984-1994.

How would I do this?

Any help would be much appreciated?

Comment: `ireland[ireland$Year>1994,]`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please search the site for existing questions before asking new ones - there are a lot of questions on SO that explain how datasets can be filtered in R.

Answer (score -1):

```
Ireland2 = Ireland[Ireland$Year < 1984 | Ireland$Year > 1994,]
```

This part:
   `Ireland$Year < 1984 | Ireland$Year > 1994`

Gets the TRUE / FALSE values for the column.

This part:
    `Ireland2 = Ireland[ ... ,]`

Creates your new data matrix, and assigns it to your new variable.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this.

```
df <- subset(ireland, Year > 1994)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked.

Comment: Wondering why got down votes.... anyone willing to explain ?